# English word for "Zeitgeschehen" (present happenings)

Tags: meaning, word-choice, terminology, german

The German word [*Zeitgeschehen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeschehen) is a noun that describes *present happenings* in general.

*Zeitgeschehen* is most commonly used as the name of a section in media. Society, culture, news, and so on are put together and summed up in that section.

I think *current events* or similar words don't work because that would exclude the society and culture part of the term and would be more comparable to *current news*.

Is there an English word for this?

Comment: "Current events" is not really used as "current news" in the US.  "News" is used for the news.  However, it seems that every newspaper has it's own way to parse that information between sections entitled "Happenings", the "Society" section, the "Metro" section, "Events", "Lifestyle" section, etc.  Maybe one of our members has a good hypernym for that collection of assorted data.

Comment: I don't think there is. This perhaps reflects a more analytical mindset in the English-speaking world. The [Sunday Times](http://www.thesundaytimes.co.uk/sto/) has the section and subsections: **News** >> _UK News_ >>
National / 
Education / 
Royal / 
Society / 
People / 
Green / 
Arts / 
Science / 
Defence / 
Health / 
Tech //,  as well as **Culture** and **Style** (and other) sections.

Comment: Sounds like [***whazzup***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wassup#English).

Comment: Why not incorporate zeitgeschehen into English? It happened with kindergarten, gesundheit and quite a few more. If you can't lick 'em, join 'em (although of course Germany was licked twice in the past 100 years).

Comment: It is not a newspaper expression but ***current affairs*** is a well-understood term in Britain. BBC Radio4 has many excellent *current affairs programmes*.

Comment: Perhaps "news of the day and cultural events" ?

Comment: _Current events_ looks quite fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are many terms that are used in American mewspapers to distinguish the types of news in the section. But all of the newspaper (except the ads) could be said to "news" or "current events".  So this is much too broad.  A few more specific section titles that you might find, standalone or in combinations:

- Around the Town (society news, gossip, "human interest" stories)
- Arts (art shows, artist interviews—sometimes includes architecture and architects)
- Books (reviews, new releases, best-seller lists, book fair info)
- Culture  (dance, drama, opera, symphony & classical music)
- Dining (restaurant reviews and "guides")
- Entertainment (see Arts, Music, Culture)
- Lifestyle (anything from recreation to home remodeling, to cooking, to anything else people do that's worth writing about)
- Movies
- Music (new releases, reviews, top-seller list, performer interviews, upcoming concerts, etc.)
- Television (weekly schedule, higlights and reviews of shows)
- Travel (ideas for car trips, tours, etc)
- Weekend (what's going on during the upcoming weekend)

Generically speaking, these are all subsets of **events, happenings,** or **goings-on** (though the latter is rarely heard anymore in AmE).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the English word you're looking for is 'zeitgeist'. I'm sure you can guess its etymology.

You're right that 'current events' (or more usually 'current affairs') would be understood to mean political news or world events. The term doesn't really capture social trends or cultural mood in the same way as 'zeitgeist'.

Comment: Zeitgeist is more of a philosophical term to denote the way people feel, think, political developments. etc. whereas zeitgeschehen has more of an active connotation, of things happening now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be counter-intuitive, but perhaps "the events of the day" can be an appropriate translation.

Answer (score 0):

Does ***[situation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/situation)*** work for you?

OED:

> A set of circumstances in which one finds oneself; *a state of
>   affairs*:
>
> - The political situation in Russia